# How can I number each item in this list? Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I am new to python.

See this below gives the output 1a,1b,1c etc. How would I make it give me the output 1a, 2b, 3c, ..?

```
range = range(1,4)
list = ['a','b','c']
for each in range:
    for i in list:
        print str(each) + i
```

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: If for some reason you didn't want to use `enumerate` but wanted to use `range`, then you could do `for each, i in zip(range, list):`.

Comment: Thanks agf that is a nice way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your problem is using *two* for loops. Why not just keep things simple and use something like:

```
myrange = range(1,4)
mylist = ['a','b','c']
for each in myrange:
    print str(each)+mylist[each-1],
```

Comment: Thanks Kaustubh. That integrated perfectly with what I was trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

Use `enumerate`. This'll show you what it does:

```
for num, let in enumerate(mylist, 1):
    print num, let
```

By the way, don't name your variable "list". It covers up the built-in `list()`.

Comment: See the documentation on the [enumerate built-in function](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: If you use the `print a, b, c...` method, you'll get spaces between the indexs and the letters. Plus, enumerate starts at 0, so you'll get `0 a`, `1 b`, so on and so forth.

Comment: @agf Nice. I didn't know about the `start` parameter.

Comment: @JoelCornett `enumerate` starts at whatever you want it to -- `enumerate(mylist, 1)` starts at 1. He already knows how to `print` them without a space in between.

Comment: He (or she) already knows how to combine a number and a string. He needs to know about `enumerate`. Good point about start though, it's relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Note that you shouldn't use `list` as a variable name -- it hides the built-in `list`.
The following code uses `myList` instead:

```
for index, val in enumerate(myList, start=1):
    print "%d%s" % (index, val)
```